# MATLAB R2017a VideoWriter error: invalid properties

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have recently upgraded from MATLAB R2016a to R2017a (also changed from Windows 7, now using Windows 10). Trying to run my existing code (nothing changed) using `VideoWriter` to create a video object, I'm getting the following error, when I get to the stage of writing the video:

```
Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 369)
One or more properties of the video is invalid. Ensure 'Quality' and 'FrameRate' property of the object and the frame dimensions are within allowed range.
```

This is my code to save the video:

```
v = VideoWriter('vidOutput','MPEG-4');
v.FrameRate = 240;
open(v);
for i = 1:size(data,2)
... code that plots an image frame...
F = getframe;
pause(0.000001)
writeVideo(v,F.cdata);
end
```

The issue seems to be with the FrameRate property. When it's set to more than 150, the error happens. Anything lower than 150 runs ok. Important to note, that when running on MATLAB R2016a, it did work with `FrameRate = 240`.

Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Is this specific to the MPEG-4 codec? Sounds like a question that might best be addressed to The MathWorks. Have tried filing a [service request](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/)?

Comment: Thanks. Filed a service request, see how this evolves.